# Overload operators for self-defined messages

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to overload operators for self-defined ROS messages? Say I have a vector message and I want to implement the multiplication by a scalar value.

EDIT: I know I can do it, as they are just classes, and they will be available at building time. But I was wondering what problems can occur and if this is a bad practice.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214298/overload-operators-for-self-defined-messages/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-22**:
This is because I want to avoid doing a lot of conversions between for example pose msgs and pose representation to operate on them. It will have small impact on performance, but the lines of code will be reduced, together with "error-proneness" when coding.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-22**:
Wouldn't there be only a conversion at the 'entrance' and at the 'exit' of your business logic?

In any case: it is actually 'accepted practice' to convert stuff to-and-fro ROS msgs. See fi [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2) and its many `tf2_bullet`, `tf2_kdl` etc conversion pkgs.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-22**:
There will be 2 conversions per type, but if I use many types, like Vector, Matrix, Quaternion, etc, there would be lots of conversions.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-07-22**:
For exactly these types there are already conversion packages to tf, Eigen.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-07-22**:
Those are just an example (those are not self-defined messages). But in any case this post is about the practice of avoiding conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not saying it can't be done, but it is generally recommended to keep your 'business logic' *ROS agnostic*. Doing what you suggest seems to inherently lead to code that uses ROS messages as variable types throughout, and thus completely violating the recommendation.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0